# azuredns for dns01 challenge for the internal domain of any organization?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, cert-manager, azure-dns

The setup in the organization is, the domain is within organization, so is its dns server. The kubernetes cluster is setup within datacenter vmware infrastructure. And this cluster (k8s-dc.<org.domain>) must be internal and so are the applications deployed in the cluster.

Ingress controller is traefik is in use, metallb is provisioned with 10 IPs from same CIDR block of k8s cluster. And there is a wildcard record for LB IP which is pointed to traefik service. Things are working pretty fine so far and plain http applications are accessible through traefik ingress controller.

The issue is all started with enabling tls certs for applications.
The organization cant open either ports 80/443 to internet for LetsEncrypt http01/tls01 challenge. So the idea is to go with dns01 challenge. The organization don't have acme supported external dns provider, so is it advisable to use azureDNS for subdomain delagation?

The sub domain in fact has been delegated to azure and its resolvable from internet. **ClusterIssuer** has been in place with all necessary azuredns config.

```
Status:
```

Acme:
Last Registered Email:  xyz@yzx.se
Uri:                    https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/452015810
Conditions:
Last Transition Time:  2022-03-15T15:26:23Z
Message:               The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
Observed Generation:   1
Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered
Status:                True
Type:                  Ready
Events:

**certiificaterequest is stuck in pending:**

Status:
Conditions:
Last Transition Time:  2022-03-15T15:35:14Z
Message:               Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
Reason:                cert-manager.io
Status:                True
Type:                  Approved
Last Transition Time:  2022-03-15T15:35:14Z
Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order rbac-test/cert-to-use-8gmj7-3966242034: "pending"
Reason:                Pending
Status:                False
Type:                  Ready
Events:

My question here is, the LB IP is internal to organization and the wildcard entry is made within organization. When the nslookup -type=NS k8s-dc.<org.domain> is made from within organization, the nameservers are resolved to internal nameservers but from outside internet, they are resolved to azureDNS. I think I'm missing something in the whole setup, how can I use azuredns for dns01 challenge for the internal domain of any organization?

Comment: You can't. The DNS resolution must be public to use Let's Encrypt. Internal domains (private zones) are not public. You will need to create a CSR and purchase a certificate from a CA.

Comment: I solved it by delegating subdomain to azure public dns zone. thanks for the response.